# Error: "Not compatible with requested type" when plotting varImp

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, r-caret

When training a model in R with the `caret` package, I get an error when plotting variable importances of the model. This happens for several mining algorithms (bayesglm, glm, naive_bayes, ...).

```
control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                      number = iterations,
                      savePredictions = TRUE,
                      classProbs = TRUE,
                      sampling = "smote");

modelFit <- train(formulaToUse,
                data = dataToAnalyze,
                method = miningAlgorithm, 
                family = "binomial", 
                preProcess = NULL, 
                trControl = control,
                tuneLength = 4);

plot(varImp(modelFit, scale = TRUE));
```

results in:

```
Error in auc_(actual, predicted, ranks) : 
Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].
```

Note that the models are mined with success, `summary(modelFit)` shows information about the model.

**Any ideas?**

R version is 3.4.3, caret is caret_6.0-79.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What are the data types of the variables you are working with. Seems like one might be a character and the plotting function is having a problem with that.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll do that the next time. Your were right, one parameter in the formula is a factor based on character values. If I remove it from the formula,  `varImp` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments: The cause was that one parameter in the formula was based on the character values. The solution is to remove this parameter (or to map / convert it to another data type).